# slow(er) SELECTs on Postgres index in Python script

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I've recently migrated a simple single-column DB (this column is indexed TEXT) from SQLite to PostgreSQL. This column has ~100m rows and i use to simply check if the column contains a certain text value.

[please avoid recommending better options for this simple problem as i need to use PostgreSQL in future for another app requiring fast select queries anyway.]

The problem I'm having is select queries are around 8x slower than SQLite, at around 140k selects per minute looping over the same text file.

I've simplified the code as much as possible (using psycopg2 library here, and omitted pvt info):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    cnt=0
    conn = get_conn()
    c = conn.cursor()
    for line in f:
        c.execute('SELECT mycol from mytbl where mycol = %s', (line.strip(),))
        if c.fetchone():
            pass
        else:
            pass
        cnt += 1
        print(cnt)
```

sqlite3 test is the same, with same single indexed column DB structure.

some clues:

- The DB is hosted my local PC
- The index is created implicitly using the primary key constraint
- Query plan: Index Only Scan using mycol_pkey on mytable

Comment: Your table and select has only a single column and you've indexed it.  There is not much else which can be done to improve performance here.

Comment: You running the same query over and over in a loop. That is not going to scale. Postgres has a much higher per-statement overhead then an embedded engine like SQLite. Why don't you create a single statement along the lines of `select count(*) from mytable where mycol in (.....)` - I am sure this will be a **lot** faster. If you can't do that you should at least use a "prepared statement" which should be parsed and optimized only once, rather then making the database parse essentially the same statement over and over again

Comment: What is the actual ```EXPLAIN ANALYZE``` for the query? Have you run ```ANALYZE``` on the table?

Comment: Which is 140000 per minutes, pgsql or sqllite?